# How are triangular waves generated in an inverter?

Tags: inverter

How do they generate the triangular wave in an actual traction inverter motor?
I believe it is from a chip and FPGA, but how do they do it?

Also, they need the sine waves for the inverter too.  Is that from the motor?  If so how exactly do we need to control the sine waves before inputting them into the comparators?

[Here's how I knew about the use of triangular waves in inverters](https://youtu.be/qVeERT4nyz8).

Comment: What is a "traction inverter motor"? An electric automobile motor? Why do you think there are triangle waves? Look up YouTube for VFD (variable frequency drive) for some tutorials. Please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly you are asking about.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE ! Your question has too few details. Please add a circuit diagram or a block diagram from where you found this *info* about sine waves, triangle waves, *chip* and FPGA.

Comment: I think the "triangular waveform" you are referring to is actually called a "Carrier Counter". This is a counter that is configured as a center aligned, and it is used as a reference timer to implement the sinusoidal pulse width modulation signals.

Comment: Why would you use an FPGA for this? That seems like a needless expense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a modern inverter, the PWM signal would be generated by microcontroller or FPGA hardware. Software would set the duty cycle for each pulse as part of a digital feedback control system. No triangle wave is needed.

In an analog circuit, a triangle wave can be generated by feeding a square wave into an integrator. Here's a simple example of such a circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0W9C4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: great that is what I needed, do you know what that feedback loop looks like for the FPGA?

Comment: Motor control isn’t really my thing. Generally, there will be a current control loop wrapped in a speed control loop wrapped in a position control loop. For the current control loop, look up Park and Clarke transforms for synchronous motors.